# How to show X - AxisLabel horizontally in chart control of ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am facing issue in showing x-axis labels horizontally. By default its showing vertically which is less readable to user. Any one came across this issue? what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer by myself..!

Somebody added below code which was rotating the X- Axis labels. Just need to be comment it.

```
 cspace.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -90
```